# Populating a treeview from a list

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

At the moment I have a hardcoded treeview in a winform set up with the following code:

```
        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode _leftCameraNode = new TreeNode("LeftCamera");
        TreeNode _rightCameraNode = new TreeNode("RightCamera");
        TreeNode[] stereoCameraArray = new TreeNode[] { _leftCameraNode, _rightCameraNode };

        TreeNode _screenNode = new TreeNode("Screen");
        TreeNode _cameraNode = new TreeNode("Camera", stereoCameraArray);

        TreeNode[] headNodeArray = new TreeNode[] { _cameraNode };
        TreeNode _headNode = new TreeNode("HeadNode", headNodeArray);

        TreeNode[] centreNodeArray = new TreeNode[] { _screenNode, _headNode };
        TreeNode _centreNode = new TreeNode("CentreNode", centreNodeArray);

        // root node
        TreeNode[] inmoRootNodeArray = new TreeNode[] { _centreNode };
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Main Node", inmoRootNodeArray);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
    }
```

This works fine, however it is very limiting in its functionality. What I really want this to do is be populated from a list of nodes that I've set up and filled out with information that I'm getting from a bunch of text boxes on my form.

For example, I create a new list of screens (child of my node class) like so:

```
    public  List<HV_Screen> _screenList = new List<HV_Screen>();
```

Then I fill out my list with the data entered from my text box like this:

```
     if (_selectedNode > -1)
        {
            Node n = _nodeList[_nodeList.Count - 1];
            n.Name = _screenName;
        }
```

I've been looking around on the net and on stackoverflow but I can't find anything to help me out with dynamically creating my treeview, so I was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction and help me out in how to do this?

The reason I want to do this is because, say I have 3 different instances of my screen, I want my treeview to show this, Then if I change the name in screen1 to MYSCREEN, I want my treeview to show this. But, should I click screen2, the treeview will still show the default name. Then, when I click back on screen1, its new name MYSCREEN will still be there on display.

I hope that makes sence.

*Edit*

Following on from a comment here is a screenshot of my current GUI:
[image]

The tree structure there has all be hard coded in with the code above. This takes in no information from my class screen class.

Now, my HV_Screen class looks as follows:

```
 private string WIDTH;
    private string HEIGHT;

    public string Width
    {
        get { return WIDTH; }
        set { WIDTH = value; }
    }

    public string Height
    {
        get { return HEIGHT; }
        set { HEIGHT = value; }
    }

    public override List<XmlElement> GenerateXML(XmlDocument _xmlDoc)
    {

       List<XmlElement> elementList = new List<XmlElement>();

        XmlElement _screenName = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("ScreenName");
        _screenName.SetAttribute("Name", name.ToString());
        _screenName.InnerText = name.ToString();
        elementList.Add(_screenName);

        XmlElement _screenTag = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("ScreenTag");
        _screenTag.SetAttribute("Tag", tag.ToString());
        _screenTag.InnerText = tag.ToString();
        elementList.Add(_screenTag);

        XmlElement _localPosition = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("LocalPosition");
        _localPosition.SetAttribute("X", XPOS.ToString());
        _localPosition.SetAttribute("Y", YPOS.ToString());
        _localPosition.SetAttribute("Z", ZPOS.ToString());
        _localPosition.InnerText = WorldPos.ToString();
        elementList.Add(_localPosition);


        XmlElement _orientation = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("Orientation");
        _orientation.SetAttribute("Yaw", YAW.ToString());
        _orientation.SetAttribute("Pitch", PITCH.ToString());
        _orientation.SetAttribute("Roll", ROLL.ToString());
        _orientation.InnerText = Orientation.ToString();
        elementList.Add(_orientation);

        XmlElement _width = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("Width");
        _width.SetAttribute("Width", WIDTH.ToString());
        _width.InnerText = WIDTH.ToString();
        elementList.Add(_width);

        XmlElement _height = _xmlDoc.CreateElement("Height");
        _height.SetAttribute("Height", HEIGHT.ToString());
        _height.InnerText = HEIGHT.ToString();
        elementList.Add(_height);

        return elementList;
    }
```

Nothing too major. This simply takes in the information and writes it to an xml file. I plan on doing this for each of my Node children. So, if I was to have a camera class, it would have its own generate XML function and write it out from there. My base class (node) simply has a bunch of getters and setters for things like name, tag etc.

With the way the code is set up at the moment, I can add in new nodes. First I must select the root node I want to branch from, then I fill out the information associated with it. So in that screen shot, if I was to select Main Node and then hit the Add button, Sample Name would now be a child of Main Node. However, if I was to select Sample and Name and change it, nothing would happen.

This way is also hard coded in to only relate to my screen class. In theory, I could simply turn a lot of different text boxes on and off but this would be really bad practise. And I'm pretty sure it will have an impact on my programs performance.

So again, what I want is one Name text box that will be in charge of filling out the name for every object that requires a name. Then, I wish to take the name I entered and have it fill out the treeview. Once I select it, I want my selected node to fill out the textboxes with all of the associated text I put in for it. But, should I change the name of my selected node, it will also change the name in the tree structure.

Again, sorry if that is confusing. I'm pretty beat at the moment.

Comment: What is in HV_Screen?...and how does it allow you to represent a Tree structure?  We're gonna need more details if you want help.  A screenshot of your GUI might help us understand better too...

Comment: I've put in more information

Comment: You would me much happier if you were using WPF for this, which supports (real) databinding, and simplifies a LOT these kind of Master/Detail scenarios.